# Every boundary simplex appears even number of times, but not a cycle?

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

If we have a set $S$ of $n$-simplices in a simplicial complex $X$, is it possible that for each $(n-1)$-simplex $\Delta$ in $X$, there is an even number of $n$-simplices in $S$ which have $\Delta$ as a boundary face, yet no $f : S \to \{-1, 1\}$ makes $\sum_{s \in S} f(s)s$ a cycle?

Comment: Is $S$ a finite set?

Comment: Does it change anything? I'm asking this because to me requiring every boundary simplex to appear an even number of times seems a more intuitive way to define cycles, and I'm wondering if it actually works.

Comment: Is plane subdivided by equilateral triangles which form a triangular lattice a cycle?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's considered a cycle? Technically it should be since its boundary is 0? In any case, what about when $S$ is finite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you're working with integer coefficients. Consider a triangulation of the Klein bottle or the real projective plane, for example: every 1-simplex appears in the boundary of exactly two 2-simplices, but there are no nonzero 2-cycles.